# How to query sparql by value

Tags: sparql, ontology, protege

I have ontology data (ontobible.owl) and its ready to download in https://teamtrainit.com/ontobible.owl

I have open it in Protege (Protege-5.5.0) like this screenshot
[image]

how to **sparql query** to select data where Verse is 1CH11_1 or 1CH11_2 and display verse_text, hasPerson,hasPlace?

Edit:
i've learn about sparql and try with dbpedia, I run this query in dbpedia,

```
SELECT * WHERE { 
           ?person rdfs:label "Jesus"@en; 
           dbo:abstract ?abstract 
           }
```

its works

but when I try similar query with ontobible.owl in protege, it doesnt works

Comment: what did you try so far? I mean, tutorials and SPARQL specs are online available

Comment: @UninformedUser i've learn about sparql and try with dbpedia,
I run  this query in dbpedia, its works

        SELECT *
        WHERE
        {
                 ?person rdfs:label "Jesus"@en;
                 dbo:abstract ?abstract
        }

but when I try similar query with ontobible.owl in protege, it doesnt works

Comment: well, you have to adapt your query to the properties and data in your ontology of course. I mean, you have to use your properties with your URIs. I doubt you have a property `dbo:abstract` in your data, and `dbo:abstract` resolves to the full URI `<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract>` - so the question is, how does the query in your local data looks like? Which query does not work?